# Git pull / fetch taking a long time

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am kind of new to Git but have read the documentation and I am unable to identify when talking to my bitbucket repository is so slow. I have 2 end points, a dev environment and a testing. Testing is where I am having problems, I am only pulling from test. Git pull or git fetch will take over 10 minutes to run. The code is 3 files 1 3KB PowerShell Script, 1KB Config file and 1 13KB PowerShell Script. Are there any git log files or troubleshooting measures I can take. When reading around I found `git fsck && git gc --prune=now` which when run before git pull / fetch will sometimes work but generally doesn't.

Troubleshooting:

- Removed bitbucket credentials from Windows Credential manager and re-entered
- Removed repository and re-cloned
- Disabled Windows Firewall for Private networks (Which is what is selected)

Extra Information

- OS: Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC
- Code Location: C:\Releases\ProjectName

Comment: Do you have separate remotes for dev and test? Sounds like something I've bumped into

Comment: @ColeTierney Nope, they both reference the same Master branch and URL - `https://bitbucket.org/teamname/projectname.git`

Comment: How are dev and test related to the repository? Are they separate local directories?

Comment: @ColeTierney Dev & Test are 2 seperate machines. Dev is where I am pushing the code from & test is where I am pulling the code. Test is the machine having problems, there is no problems with Push / Pull from Dev

Comment: `git pull` literally runs `git fetch` (it means "run fetch, then run a second Git command") so if `git fetch` is stalling, that explains the whole thing. Why `git fetch` is stalling is a separate question. Since you're using `https://` rather than `ssh://` you are going through the SSL layers; it would be interesting to see if those affect other uses, e.g., browsers going to `https` URLs, at both bitbucket.org and other sites.

Comment: @torek exactly my assumption, why I mentioned `git fetch`. `git pull` also runs `git merge` and that is not what's stalling. I will try give SSH a go and see what results that returns.

Comment: Is the Test machine seriously overloaded (I'm guessing it's a build/test farm) ? In that case, git fetch may take some time since just the disk accesses may be slow...

Comment: @Khoyo Nope it's just a Windows 10 box with nothing else on it.